# Issue with getting onMouseOver and onClick to work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have a problem with `onClick` and `onMouseOver`, and am trying to resolve using pure JavaScript.

I have 2 images, when cursor is over the `image1` the `image2` appears, and this `image2` has a function that is called with `onClick()`.

Im using a function to change id to show/hide image(using CSS)

```js
function show()
{
    document.getElementById('ferramenta1').id='ferramenta100';
}

function hide()
{
    document.getElementById('ferramenta100').id='ferramenta1';  
}
```

```html
<!-- image 1 -->

<img src="imagens/favNulo.png" onMouseOver="show()" onMouseOut="hide()" id="favorito1" title="Favorito n°1" style="cursor:pointer;"/>

<!-- image 2 -->
<img src="imagens/ferramentaFavoritos.png" onClick="editarTelaFav()"  onMouseOver="show()"  id="ferramenta1" title="Editar favorito n°1" style="cursor:pointer"/>
```

Images are changed correctly, but `onClick` doesn't work.

I found some post's similar to this in StackOverflow, but neither is resolved without jQuery.

**EDIT:** the onclick code

```
function editarTelaFav() {
   var fer1 = document.getElementById("ferramenta1").id;

   if (window.event.srcElement.id == fer1) {
     window.open('favoritoNumero1.jsp','','left=50%,top=50%,height=600,width=800');
   }
 }
```

Comment: what does your onclick code look like?

Comment: are those `...` meant to be in the code? they will mess JS up

Comment: <code> function editarTelaFav(){ var code = 0; var fer1= document.getElementById("ferramenta1").id; ... if(window.event.srcElement.id == fer1){ code=1; }... if(code==1){ window.open('favoritoNumero1.jsp','','left=50%,top=50%,height=600,width=800'); } } </code> thanks for answer!

Comment: I am striving to put in code mode, so sorry. but ctrl+k and <code> doesnt work

Comment: Press the code sample in the editor, @Morre I edited the question to format code originally OP obviously isn't used the the editor

Comment: I just looked at your code for the first time - you are changing element IDs??? Don't do that! Work with the ones you've got, and change the STYLES!

Comment: @user1991144 For future reference, anything with four (4) spaces in front of it in edit mode will be formatted into a code block after you save your edits. In edit mode, you can also paste in or write the code, highlight it, and then hit the `{ }` button along the row of tools above the edit textbox and it will automatically indent your code into a code block. There is a preview window below your edit window to show you what your post will look like.

Comment: I change the id image and i edit in CSS. Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

this bit of logic will never return 1

```
if(window.event.srcElement.id == fer1){ code=1; }
```

Because everytime you show it you change the id to 'ferramenta100'

```
document.getElementById('ferramenta1').id='ferramenta100';
```

tbh I don't understand what that `if` statement is meant to do, remove it and it'll work fine, so:

```
function editarTelaFav(){ 

window.open('favoritoNumero1.jsp','','left=50%,top=50%,height=600,width=800'); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, guess I was not very clear. This "..." is here because i have other 6 elements. `code 
var fer1= document.getElementById("ferramenta1").id; 
var fer2= document.getElementById("ferramenta2").id;... 

if(code==1){window.open'favoritoNumero1.jsp';} if(code==2){window.open('favoritoNumero2.jsp');} `

Comment: It's still valid, when you show the image you change it's id, you then test for the old id, so your if block will never return true and your click will never work

Answer (score 0):

you can use hover from css to change the image by that you will end up with one JavaScript command maybe that will help.
in your css

```
#hoverchange  a {
width:64px;
height:64px;
background-image: url(imagens/favNulo.png);
display:block;
}

#hoverchange  a:hover {
background-image: url(imagens/ferramentaFavoritos.png);
}
```

the width and height should be your image width and height.

and in your html

```
<div id="hoverchange">
<a href="#!" onClick="editarTelaFav()"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question. the question isn't how do I change the image it's why is the onclick not working

Comment: maybe if he change the image that way the onclick going to work in the end!!